# flutter web imagepicker always returns null

Tags: flask

I'm trying to load an image onto a widget through imagepickerweb/filepicker but both give me null bytes which lead to the image not being able to load.

```
addFile() async {
  imageBytes = await ImagePickerWeb.getImageAsBytes().then((image) {
    if (image != null) {
      imageBytes = image;
      imageChosen = true;
      print(imageBytes);
    }
    print(imageBytes);
  });
  setState(() {});
}
```